# jumping button and White space in the bottom of the page

Tags: css

my HTML looks like this. i was trying to make a landing page with a cover and a button. this is my first time working on a real project and stumble upon this problem where the page does not have much elements and just a button

```css
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .wrap {
      background-image: url("../desktop.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 39.9375em) {
      .wrap {
        background-image: url("../mobile.jpg");
      }
    }
    
    .btn {
      font-size: 1rem;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 1rem 4rem;
      background: #e6a503;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: 900;
      color: black;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 100ms ease-in-out;
      transition: opacity 100ms ease-in-out;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
      opacity: 0.9;
    }
    
    .btn:active {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.98);
              transform: scale(0.98);
    }
    
    .btn-container {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20%;
      left: 25%;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 39.9375em) {
      .btn-container {
        top: 35%;
        left: 70;
      }
    }
```

```html
   <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css" />
        <title>title</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="wrap">
          <div class="btn-container">
            <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="btn" target="_blank"
              >အကောင့်ဖွင့်ရန်</a
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

what is causing the white space? also my button is jumping around in different browsers
pls help. thanks in advance.

[this white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XScDM.png)

Comment: i have tried many solutions on the problem looking throughs posts in the website but nothing works so far

Comment: I don't understand which whitespace you are tacking about?

Comment: @BadPiggie sorry about that. i have added the picture

Comment: @BadPiggie i tried removing height:100vh; and 100% . it doesnt work

Comment: Hi, tin. Welcome to stack overflow. Which browser are you using (I cannot reproduce the error). Also try to set `top: 0` on body and `margin: 0` on wrap.

Comment: chrome. but the error is across all browsers. could the size of image be the source of problem? the picture size is 640x960 for mobile

Comment: ok, your problem is not with the body. As you imagine is with the image. The problem is not the size. I better post an answer it will be more clarify.

Comment: @ÒscarRaya hello my button disappeared in ipad viewport and i cant find my button when i hover over my button in elements .whats wrong?

Comment: Are you using chrome development tools to see iPad view right? Your current web shows the button. Can you update it?

Comment: Also if it happends to be a different problem you may need to open a new question (its stackoverflow rules). In fact you should post one question for each problem.

Comment: @tin please explain your question better and put your question before  the huge code snippet, instead of splitting it in 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the css used to place the background image. If you want the image to cover all the background you first need to place it on the body. Not on the `wrap`.

Then use the following css:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../desktop.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

As you can see I changed `background-position` to `center`.

In case you really wanted to use the image only on the wrap then also change the `background-position` to `center`. Also you need the following css on wrap to ensure it fits the whole page:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
```

Notice the `position: absolute;` which is necessary in order to `top:0` to work. In desktop it works just fine. It may be possible that on mobile the wrap component isn't covering the whole windows.

Regarding the centering of your button take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center_button.asp). Just use the following css on the button container:

```
.btn-container{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

As you can see, instead of using top and left with 33% it uses 50% and then it transforms the position of the button 50% to the left of the button (this last 50% is accordint to the button size).

Comment: thanks. it fixed my problem. thanks for teaching

Comment: i dont quite get the transform translate. i am going for a video on the topic and get back at it again. thanks for sharing your wisdom